# How to rotate the Tabs(With text) by 90° in Notebook widget tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

The title preety much says it. If it's not possible, then what can be some other workarounds to get similar results.
I changed the behavior of Notebook tab with the following-

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('400x200')

        ttk.Style().element_create('Plain.Notebook.tab', 'from', 'default')
        ttk.Style().layout('TNotebook.Tab',
                           [('Plain.Notebook.tab', {'children':
                                [('Notebook.padding', {'side': 'top', 'children':
                                     [('Notebook.focus', {'side': 'top', 'children':
                                          [('Notebook.label', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''})],
                                      'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                                 'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                            'sticky': 'nswe'})])
        ttk.Style().configure('TNotebook', background='red', borderwidth=0)
        ttk.Style().configure('TNotebook.Tab', font=('Segoe UI', 14),
                              background='black', foreground='white', borderwidth=0)

        tab = ttk.Notebook(self)
        frm1 = tk.Frame(tab)
        tab.add(frm1, text='Frame1')
        frm2 = tk.Frame(tab)
        tab.add(frm2, text='Frame2')
        tab.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        canv1 = tk.Canvas(frm1, bg='#0000FF')
        canv2 = tk.Canvas(frm2, bg='#00FF00')
        canv1.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        canv2.pack(expand=1, fill='both')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Root().mainloop()
```

Also that `tabposition` is not what I want, I want the individual Tab buttons and the text to be vertical too. Are there any workarounds for this purpose?
[image: This is what my app currently looks like.]
And this is how I want it to be-
[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Comment: Recent versions of Tkinter are able to produce rotated text on a Canvas, but I'm not seeing any way to replace the Notebook's tabs with a widget of your own - the only way you'd be able to do this would be to have images (of rotated text) instead of text for the tabs.

Comment: @jasonharper yeah, by using images it'd be pretty simple to implement it just like I did with the navbar on the left. Also can you tell me how to make Notebook tab buttons to be simple flat Rectangular button rather than curved on the edges as that's how it's right now with the layout in the code above and I don't like it.